# How to push data into 2nd location in C++

Tags: c++, casting, struct

Suppose I have below program,

```
 typedef struct xyz
    {
    int abc[6];//int abc;
    //int yz;
    }xyz;
    int main()
    {
    int *ptr = new int(10);
    int *ptr1 = new int(20);

    xyz* XYZ = reinterpret_cast <xyz*>(ptr); //Initializes XYZ->abc[0]
    XYZ = reinterpret_cast <xyz*>(ptr1);//Initializes XYZ->abc[0]

    }
```

Here the value enters into `zeroth location`. If I would like to push the value into `XYZ->abc[1]`, then how can I do this?

Comment: Actually, that’s totally undefined C++ code. What exactly do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: You need to use pointer arithmetics

Comment: And I recommend you to use shared pointers

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I would like to initialize all the struct members. How to do this?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak By writing a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do

```
 XYZ = reinterpret_cast<xyz*> (ptr1+1);
```

But this kind of code is disgusting, it probably is an **undefined behavior** (because `ptr1+1` might not be a valid location, and you could get a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)), so you should avoid doing that.

I actually don't understand the motivation (and use case) of your question.

Maybe you wanted to allocate ten ints on the heap. Then code

```
int *ptr = new int[10];
```

and don't forget to initialize them, e.g. with `memset (ptr, 0, sizeof(int)*10);`

On Linux systems, I strongly suggest to compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and `gdb` to debug your program. You really want to know these tools.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure this is UB. Note that ptr1 isn't an array, it's a pointer to a single `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any casting:

```
xyz val;

val.abc[0] = 1234;
val.abc[1] = 5678;
```

or if you need a dynamically allocated instance:

```
xyz* ptr = new xyz();

ptr->abc[0] = 1234;
ptr->abc[1] = 5678;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
xyz XYZ;
XYZ.abc[1] = *ptr;
```

Comment: May be u r right. But my program needs to be like the way I asked.

Comment: @Rasmi: But you are trying to write values into a structure that doesn't exist - you have no xyz instance so none of the casts are valid.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak so you can't change the program? So then why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to initialize all the struct members.

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour and is far, far more complex than necessary. If all you want to do is initialise the structure, create a constructor:

```
struct xyz {
    int a[6];

    xyz() : a() { }
};
```

Now if you create an object of type `xyz`, it gets initialised:

```
int main() {
    xyz XYZ;
}
```

Notice how much shorter easier this solution is. It also doesn’t use pointers or manual memory management and doesn’t leak memory. Oh, and it also doesn’t use the `typedef struct …`  construct which is completely unnecessary in C++.

Comment: @Rasmi So? That’s not a problem. Just add an appropriate constructor to initialise it with values other than 0 (however, if you’re not using C++11 this will require doing it manually in the constructor).